# Pandas handle negative value when doing operations such as sum()

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a way to convert my `Revenue` column from object
to numeric but still keep negative values as I am trying to do the operation below

df

```
customerId  Revenue
3443        1,323.90
4325        -442
5833        -101
9424        1,539.20
```

```
df.types:
customer_ID: int 
Revenue: object
```

```
df['Revenue'].sum()
```

This is what I have tried so far but did not work: this simply converts negative values to positive

```
df["Revenue"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Revenue"].str.strip().str.replace(",", "")).abs()
```

Comment: Try just adding `.apply(float)` instead of the `.abs()`

Comment: hi! Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 1):

Try via `strip()`,`replace()` and `astype()` method:

```
df['Revenue']=df['Revenue'].str.strip().str.replace(',','').astype(float)
```

**OR**

via `strip()`,`replace()` and `to_numeric()` method:

```
df['Revenue']=pd.to_numeric(df['Revenue'].str.strip().str.replace(',',''),errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Why the `int` at the end?

Comment: @ShlomiF In case Op want int value but removed...Thnx for noticing ***:)***

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this -

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> d = {
... 
...   'customer_id':[3443,4325,5833,9424]
...   ,'Revenue':['1,323.90',-442,-101,'1,539.20']
... }
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> 
>>> 
>>> df['Revenue']=df.loc[:,'Revenue'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace(',','')).astype(float)
>>> df
   customer_id  Revenue
0         3443   1323.9
1         4325   -442.0
2         5833   -101.0
3         9424   1539.2
>>>
```